# ConnectTimeoutError when installing earthengine-api

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, connect-timeout

I have pip 18.1 with python 3.6 and would like to install the earthengine-api so I typed `pip install earthengine-api` in a command prompt.

I got the following error message:

`Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x06345BF0>, 'Connection to 10.168.209.72 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/earthengine-api/ Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement earthengine-api (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for earthengine-api`

I tried `set | find "proxy"` and it gave:

```
https_proxy=http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx  
http_proxy=http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx  
no_proxy=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx,xxx.0.0.1
```

while `pip config list | find "proxy"` gave:

```
FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

I don't understand the error message but suspected the protections of my work PC (of which I am not administrator) to be responsible for this issue, So I decided to install python on a home PC with
`pip install earthengine-api`
but in jupyter notebook I got "no module ee"
So I installed it with
`conda install –c conda-forge earthengine-api`
and now it works in jupyter (don't ask me why).

Comment: What is the question exactly??

Comment: Question 1: Why did I get I ConnectTimeoutError when installing earthengine-api? I assumed it had to see with my PC configuration (but what exactly?) so I changed PC and it worked.  Question 2: earthengine was installed successfully ,however it did not work in the Jupyter notebook (and I have the same problem with Geopandas, which I had to install through 5 different packages), so what should I do? I found out I should use conda to install earthengine and I think this may be helpful for others. For Geopandas, I am still searching for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your first installation of the `earthengine-api` package  with pip installed the it as a system wide package, and probably not in a conda environment.

The python interpreter used by jupyter would I suppose be in the `base` environment of your conda installation, and so will only look for a requested package in that environment.

Try using conda to install your packages before resorting to pip. Checkout the guide here https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html

Comment: Thank you @droptop.  Do you mean installing geopandas with:  `conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas`

I am trying this way but it seems that it is taking a lot of time; I will probably abort it.  

or do you mean creating a new environment (e.g. mymap) and installing geopandas with  
`conda create --name mymap geopandas`?

or installing each package separately in this new environment using 
`conda create --name mymap fiona...` etc?

Comment: See See https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-conda-environments-bc6180fc533 for a better understanding of environments and why you'll want to use them/